# Como posicionar/alinhar um field (que está dentro de uma div) junto com outros fields

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Saudações a todos!

Dentro da minha "form-group row" estou posicionando os fields coms seus respectivos tamanhos, porém, no meio deles (para ser mais específico, entre o primeiro e o terceiro field) eu criei uma div (div-financeiro-fornecedor) que contém outro field e que precisa ser renderizado seguindo a proporção col-md-6, mas a "div-financeiro-fornecedor" parece estar atrapalhando. Alguém sabe como corrigir isso?

Obrigado :)

- Como está ficando:
  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

-Como deveria ser:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

-HTML/Razor:

```
<div class="form-group row">

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label asp-for="PessoaEmpresaId" class="control-label">Empresa</label>
        <select id="sel-pessoa-empresa" asp-for="PessoaEmpresaId" asp-items="Model.Empresas" title="Selecione uma opção" class="form-control" style="position: fixed !important;"><option value=""></option></select>
        <span asp-validation-for="PessoaEmpresaId" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div id="div-financeiro-fornecedor">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label asp-for="PessoaFornecedorId" class="control-label">Fornecedor</label>
            <select id="sel-financeiro-fornecedor" asp-for="PessoaFornecedorId" asp-items="Model.PessoasFornecedores" title="Selecione uma opção" class="form-control"  style="position: fixed !important;"><option value=""></option></select>
            <span asp-validation-for="PessoaFornecedorId" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label asp-for="FinanceiroTipo" class="control-label">Tipo de Controle Financeiro</label>
        <select id="sel-financeiro-tipo" asp-for="FinanceiroTipo" asp-items="Model.FinanceirosTipos" title="Selecione uma opção" class="form-control" style="position: fixed !important;"><option value=""></option></select>
        <span asp-validation-for="FinanceiroTipo" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label asp-for="NumeroDocumento" class="control-label">Número do Documento</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text">
                    <i class="icon fa-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </span>
            </div>
            <input id="txt-numero-documento" asp-for="NumeroDocumento" class="form-control text-uppercase" />
        </div>
        <span asp-validation-for="NumeroDocumento" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label asp-for="@Model.ValorDocumento" class="control-label">Valor do Documento</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text">
                    <i class="icon fa-dollar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </span>
            </div>
            <input id="txt-valor-documento" asp-for="@Model.ValorDocumento" class="form-control text-uppercase" />
        </div>
        <span asp-validation-for="@Model.ValorDocumento" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara as filhas diretas da `div=row` deve ser as `div=col`, então essa div com `ID=div-financeiro-fornecedor` na verdade deveria estar dentro da Coluna, isso que está quebrando seu grid, basicamente é só inverter a ordem aqui

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div id="div-financeiro-fornecedor">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado @hugocsl!!!!! Funcionou 100% :)

Comment: @MasterJR sem problemas meu caro!